# Tensorflow Freeze Graph node is not in graph

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to export a model that I trained using keras with a tensorflow backend into a .pb file so I can use it for android and I am getting the following error when I try to freeze my graph.

```python
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "youtubeExample.py", line 102, in <module>
      export_model(tf.train.Saver(), model, ["conv2d_1_input"], "output")
    File "youtubeExample.py", line 49, in export_model
      'out/frozen_' + MODEL_NAME + '.pb', True, "")
    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 244, in freeze_graph
      saved_model_tags.split(","), checkpoint_version=checkpoint_version)
    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 153, in freeze_graph_with_def_protos
      variable_names_blacklist=variable_names_blacklist)
    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_util_impl.py", line 232, in convert_variables_to_constants
      inference_graph = extract_sub_graph(input_graph_def, output_node_names)
    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_util_impl.py", line 174, in extract_sub_graph
      _assert_nodes_are_present(name_to_node, dest_nodes)
    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_util_impl.py", line 133, in _assert_nodes_are_present
      assert d in name_to_node, "%s is not in graph" % d
  AssertionError: output is not in graph
```

The the part of code that I use to define my model is:

```python
 model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(224,224,3)))
  model.add(Flatten()) 
  model.add(Dense(units = 2, activation='softmax', name = "output"))

  model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I would appreciate any help I could get with this  issue as I am relatively new to tensorflow/keras.

Comment: It might be helpful to add the code that tries to load the model